# How to transform the dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a requirements where I need to transform my data coming from my api in this way .

I have fixed 7 columns

```
EntityID , EntityName , ForYear , Labels , FiscalPeriodValue , ForDate , (ValueColumn)
```

My last column will always be the column which holds the value .

ForDate will be the same for each entity , ForYear will be the same but labels can be different .

The Api May return the data of 2 entities , and it may return the dataset of 2 or more entities (I dont know)

for example: My Api May Return the below data

```
data = [
{
    'EntityID': 3,
    'EntityName': 'Trading Value',
    'ForDate': '2023-07-13',
    'Labels': '2023-07-13',
    'FiscalPeriodValue': 'Daily',
    'ForYear': 2023,
    'DataValue': 7.7
},
{
    'EntityID': 4,
    'EntityName': 'Quarterly average',
    'ForDate': '2023-07-13',
    'Labels': '2023-Q3',
    'FiscalPeriodValue': 'Daily',
    'ForYear': 2023,
    'DataValue': 7.05
},
{
    'EntityID': 5,
    'EntityName': 'Yearly average',
    'ForDate': '2023-07-13',
    'Labels': '2023',
    'FiscalPeriodValue': 'Daily',
    'ForYear': 2023,
    'DataValue': 5.21
},
# ... (other data entries)
```

]

Now We can see that It has 3 Unique Entities and all of them have same dates but different Labels

What I want is to transform this data in this way

```
data = [
{
    'D': '2023-07-13',
    'Y': 2023,
    'L1': '2023-07-13',
    'L2': '2023-Q3',
    'L3': '2023',
    'Trading Value': 7.7,
    'Quarterly average': 7.05,
    'Yearly average': 5.21
}
```

]

As we can see that Trading Value Label is date so I have make the L1 As the Label Value of Trading value entity , and so on ...

The sequence should be the same for L1 , L2 , L3 as the entity names

I have tried and make my desired dataset but without L1 , L2,L3

```
grouped_data = df.groupby('ForDate').apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['EntityName'], x[ValueColumn]))).reset_index()
     grouped_data.columns = ['ForDate', 'Data']   
     new_dataset = grouped_data.apply(lambda row: {
     **{
     'D': row['ForDate'],
     'Y': df[df['ForDate'] == row['ForDate']]['ForYear'].iloc[0],
     },
      **row['Data']
     }, axis=1).tolist()
```

The above code is what i have tried so far .

Comment: What's the question exactly? Like, what do you need help with? Please read [ask] and [edit] to clarify. See also [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341).

Comment: What dataframe library are you using? Pandas? Please make sure to include the tag for it. OneCricketeer just added it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both code snippets have same logic.

```py
import pandas as pd
data = [
    { ... },
    { ... },
    { ... },]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
pivot_df1 = df.pivot_table(index=['ForDate', 'ForYear'], columns=[
                'EntityName'], values='DataValue').reset_index()
print('-' * 20)
print(pivot_df1)

unique_df2 = df[['ForDate', 'Labels']].drop_duplicates().set_index(
    'L' + (df.groupby('ForDate').cumcount()+1).astype(str)).reset_index()
print('-' * 20)
print(unique_df2)

df3 = unique_df2.pivot(index='ForDate', columns='index', values='Labels')
print('-' * 20)
print(df3)

df4 = pivot_df1.join(df3, on='ForDate')
column_list = ['ForDate', 'ForYear', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3',
      'Trading Value', 'Quarterly average', 'Yearly average']
df4 = df4[column_list]
column_list[:2] = ['D', 'Y']
df4.columns = column_list
print('-' * 20)
json_string = df4.to_json(orient='records', indent=4)
print(json_string)
```

**Output**

```
--------------------
EntityName     ForDate  ForYear  Quarterly average  Trading Value  Yearly average
0           2023-07-13     2023               7.05            7.7            5.21
--------------------
  index     ForDate      Labels
0    L1  2023-07-13  2023-07-13
1    L2  2023-07-13     2023-Q3
2    L3  2023-07-13        2023
--------------------
index               L1       L2    L3
ForDate
2023-07-13  2023-07-13  2023-Q3  2023
--------------------
[
    {
        "D":"2023-07-13",
        "Y":2023,
        "L1":"2023-07-13",
        "L2":"2023-Q3",
        "L3":"2023",
        "Trading Value":7.7,
        "Quarterly average":7.05,
        "Yearly average":5.21
    }
]
```

---

To combine DataFrame operations into one line, use:

```py
output = pd.merge(
    (df[['ForDate', 'Labels']]
     .drop_duplicates()
     .set_index('L' + (df.groupby('ForDate').cumcount()+1).astype(str))
     .reset_index()
     .pivot(index='ForDate', columns='index', values='Labels')
     .reset_index()),
    (df.pivot_table(
        index=['ForDate', 'ForYear'],
        columns=['EntityName'],
        values='DataValue')
        .reset_index()),
    on='ForDate', how='left')
column_list = ['ForDate', 'ForYear', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3',
               'Trading Value', 'Quarterly average', 'Yearly average']
print(output[column_list])
```

---

> **Question**: the no of Entities are not fixed . so it maybe L1 only or may be up to L10

> **Answer**: Updated the code to dynamically create columns name list

```
lx_list = [f'L{str(x)}' for x in range(1, df3.shape[1] + 1)  ]
column_list =(['ForDate', 'ForYear'] + lx_list +
      ['Trading Value', 'Quarterly average', 'Yearly average'])
df4 = pivot_df1.join(df3, on='ForDate')
df4 = df4[column_list]
column_list[:2] = ['D', 'Y']
df4.columns = column_list
print('-' * 20)
json_string = df4.to_json(orient='records', indent=4)
print(json_string)
```

Comment: the no of Entities are not fixed . so it may b L1 only or may be up to L10

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you ask for correctly, you can achieve the desired result with `pivot`.

For example (I've duplicated your data for 2022; `t1` stands for "temporary variable 1"):

```py
t1 = data.set_index(['ForDate'])[['DataValue', 'EntityName']]\
    .pivot(values='DataValue', columns='EntityName')
```

Will give

```
EntityName  Quarterly average  Trading Value  Yearly average
ForDate                                                     
2022-07-13               7.05            7.7            5.21
2023-07-13               7.05            7.7            5.21
```

`.set_index` is effectively a groupby by the date, and then we "transpose" the table with `pivot`.

With labels, it's more complicated. We need to create a separate column to pivot by (I used the length of the label; you may design it differently depending on your labels). In the end, I rename the columns to "L1/L2/L3".

```py
t2 = data.set_index('ForDate')[['Labels']]
t2['pivot_by'] = t2.Labels.str.len()
t2 = t2.pivot(columns='pivot_by', values='Labels')
t2.columns = ['L1', 'L2', 'L3']
```

Lastly, we concatenate

```py
pd.concat([t1, t2], axis=1)
```

to get the end result

```
            Quarterly average  Trading Value  Yearly average    L1       L2          L3
ForDate                                                                                
2022-07-13               7.05            7.7            5.21  2022  2022-Q3  2022-07-13
2023-07-13               7.05            7.7            5.21  2023  2023-Q3  2023-07-13
```

`D` field is the index (you can get it back into the frame with `reset_index`). `Y` field can be extracted trivially from date.

Comment: the no of Entities are not fixed . so it may b L1 only or may be up to L10

Comment: You mean there can be different number of unique labels for different dates? How do you imagine the structure of your dataframe then?

Answer (score -1):

What I have tried and its working

```
   pivot_df = df.pivot(index=['ForDate', 'ForYear'], columns=['EntityName'], values=ValueColumn).reset_index()
     pivot_df.columns.name = None
     pivot_df = pivot_df.rename(columns={'ForDate': 'D', 'ForYear': 'Y'})
     label_data = df.groupby('ForDate')['Labels'].apply(list).reset_index(name='Labels')

     max_labels = max(label_data['Labels'].apply(len))  # Determine the maximum number of labels

     label_cols = [f'L{i+1}' for i in range(max_labels)]
     for col in label_cols:
      pivot_df[col] = ''

     def populate_labels(row):
      labels = label_data[label_data['ForDate'] == row['D']]['Labels'].iloc[0]
      for i, label in enumerate(labels):
       pivot_df.at[row.name, label_cols[i]] = label

     pivot_df.apply(populate_labels, axis=1)
     column_order = ['D', 'Y'] + label_cols + df['EntityName'].tolist()
     pivot_df = pivot_df[column_order]

     new_dataset = pivot_df.to_dict(orient='records')
```